# GCC and Clang seem not to obey the overload resolution in the allocation function call

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/K9dx9W5jM)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    void* operator new(std::size_t N, std::align_val_t){  // #1
        return malloc(sizeof(char)* N);
    }
};
int main(){
    auto ptr =  new A;  // #2
}
```

Both GCC and Clang complain that

```
<source>:9:17: error: no matching function for call to 'operator new'
    auto ptr =  new A;
                ^
<source>:4:11: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
    void* operator new(std::size_t N, std::align_val_t){
          ^
1 error generated.
```

However, [[expr.new]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#19) p19 says

> Overload resolution is performed on a function call created by assembling an argument list.
> The first argument is the amount of space requested, and has type std​::​size_­t.
> If the type of the allocated object has new-extended alignment, the next argument is the type's alignment, and has type std​::​align_­val_­t.
> If the new-placement syntax is used, the initializer-clauses in its expression-list are the succeeding arguments. **If no matching function is found then**
>
> > - if the allocated object type has new-extended alignment, the alignment argument is removed from the argument list;
> > - otherwise, **an argument that is the type's alignment and has type std​::​align_­val_­t is added into the argument list immediately after the first argument**;
>
> **and then overload resolution is performed again**.

The found candidate for the allocation function calling in the new expression at `#2` is `#1`. For the first time, the assembling argument list is `sizeof(A)`, which cannot make `#1` a matching function, then according to the rule, the assembling arguments will be `sizeof(A),std::align_val_t(alignof(A))`, which can make `#1` a matching function. Also, it's a typical example recorded in [[expr.new] p20](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#20)

> `new T` results in one of the following calls:
>
> > - operator new(sizeof(T))
> > - operator new(sizeof(T), std::align_val_t(alignof(T)))

Why do GCC and Clang reject this example? Is this defect of GCC and Clang? Or, Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new A()`? Or `new A[42]`?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb That's irrelevant for this example since `new-initializer` is an optional component. `new A` is sufficient to make the initialization be a default-initialization

Comment: Does a member `operator new()` not need to be `static`? There is no object to associate it to so it needs to be a class function.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.free#1

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is an interesting way of spelling `1`.

Comment: @ecatmur Right, It is not even necessary. `N` is enough to represent how much space we request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present the only major compiler that implements [CWG 2282](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2282.html) is [MSVC](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c20-features-in-visual-studio-2019-versions-16-7-and-16-8/#c20-language-feature-support). I'm not aware of any current effort or feature requests for GCC or clang.

Also, I don't believe the `__cpp_aligned_new` feature test macro has been updated for CWG 2282, so you'll need to use old-fashioned compiler version checking to determine whether the feature is available.

Comment: Ah, it's surprising that GCC and Clang fall back MSVC that generally should be the late one.

Comment: @xmh0511, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support MSVC is pretty good with standards since MSVC 2017 (before that, they were pretty terrible)